# The density of the range of a bounded linear operator on L2[0,1]

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let α be positive and define linear operator T from L2[0,1] to L2[0,1] by Tf(x)=(∮[x→1]f(t)dt)-αxf(x).Then,T is bounded.
Find the range of α such that R(T) is dense in L2[0,1].

I understand T is bounded linear operator on L2[0,1].
So,I want to use the following equation:cl(R(T))=(kerT*)⊥
Then,R(T) is dense in L2[0,1] if and only if kerT*={0}
However,I don’t know how to find the adjoint operator of T.
Please give me a hint or answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you wanted to write $Tf:=\int f\,\mathrm d \lambda -\alpha \operatorname{id}f$ for some $\alpha >0$ then you can set $Rf:=\int f\,\mathrm d \lambda $ and $S:=\alpha \operatorname{id}f$, then note that $T^*=R^*-S^*$ and
$$
\langle Rf,g \rangle=\int \left(\int f\,\mathrm d \lambda \right)\bar g\,\mathrm d \lambda =\int \overline{\left(\int g\,\mathrm d \lambda \right)}f\,\mathrm d \lambda =\langle  f,R^*g\rangle\\
\therefore \quad R^*g=Rg=\int g\,\mathrm d \lambda 
$$
Similarly we find that $S^*g=\overline{\alpha \operatorname{id}}g$.

---

In the case that $Rf:=\int_x^1 f(t)\,\mathrm d t$ then we have that
$$
\begin{align*}
\langle Rf,g \rangle&=\int_0^1\left(\int_x^1 f(t)\,\mathrm d t\right)\bar g(x) \,\mathrm d x\\&=\int_{\{(x,t):0\leqslant x\leqslant t\leqslant 1\}}f(t)\bar g(x)\,\mathrm d (x,t)\\
&=\int_0^1\left(\int_0^t\bar g(x)\,\mathrm d x\right)f(t)\,\mathrm d t\\
&=\int_0^1\overline{\left(\int_0^t g(x)\,\mathrm d x\right)}f(t)\,\mathrm d t\\
&=\langle f,R^*g \rangle
\end{align*}\\
\therefore \qquad R^*g=\int_0^t g(x)\,\mathrm d x
$$

Comment: Rf is an integration of f(t),where t move from x to 1.So,I think the exchange of integrations isn’t possible.

Comment: @ATP see my edit

Comment: Tkank you for your edit.I understand almostly,but I'm not used to lebesgue integrations of two variables.So,I'm not sure that the integration of the second line is equal to the integration of the third equation.

Comment: @ATP $L^2([0,1])$ is the space of square Lebesgue integrable real (or complex) valued functions with domain $[0,1]$, and you are not used to Lebesgue integration theory? The integral in the second line can also be written as $$\int \chi _{[x,1]}(t) f(t)\bar g(x) \,\mathrm d (x,t)=\int \chi _{[0,t]}(x) f(t)\bar g(x) \,\mathrm d (x,t)$$ Note that the integrals are well defined because $L^2([0,1])\subset L^1([0,1])$. Sorry but I cannot teach you here Lebesgue integration theory

Comment: In addition, I think for any α such that α is positive, (kerT*)⊥≠{0}.It is because g belongs to (kerT*)⊥ if and only if almost everywhere R*g=S*g and there is no constant α satisfying the condition.

Comment: I understand. How about the range of α?

Comment: @ATP I deleted my previous comment because it had an error. The indicator function $\chi _{[x,1]}(s)$ can also be written as $\chi _A(x,t)$ for $A:=\{(x,t)\in[0,1]^2: x\leqslant t\}$ (just note that both functions are exactly the same, that is, they took the same values for any chosen pair $(x,t)$), this shows why the second integral in my answer have it form. I dont follow your second comment, just note that to show that $(R-S)^*$ is injective it is enough to check that there is no $f\neq 0$ such that $R^*f=S^*f$

Comment: I have misunderstood.α=1 is satisfying the condition.

Comment: @ATP just observe that $$R^*f=S^*f\iff \int_0^x (f(t)-\bar\alpha f(x))dt=0\iff f(t)=\bar\alpha f(x) \text{ for almost every }t\in[0,x]$$ So for $\alpha=1$ the operator $T$ doesn't have dense range because for $f$ a non zero constant function the above holds

Comment: I guess you are misunderstanding about R*f and S.R*f is a function of x and Sf=αxf(x) and α is positive number,so that S*f(x)=αxf(x).When α=0,f(x)=1 on [0,1] satisfy the condition.

Comment: @ATP Im not misunderstanding something, I already knows that $R^*f$ is a function, also $S^*f$ is a function. For $\alpha =0$ the operator $T$ have dense range.

Comment: That α >0  is given.I think you are misunderstanding about R*.It need to exchange t with x.